# Complex Wordpress Loop from theme

Tags: arrays, wordpress, loops, fluid-layout

Im trying to build a gallery/portfolio page similar this one here: http://touch3.themeple.co/?page_id=130

Ive been going over this in my head and Im not an advanced enough programmer to make this work on my own. when you click one of the thumbs, the corresponding information expands directly under the thumbnail and pushes the content under it down.

Really quick, the way it appears to work is:

each row of thumbnails go into a div called "fluid-grid".

Under that row of thumbs, the corresponding information is rendered in its own hidden div, respectively.

when you click on a thumbnail, the information expands directly below the thumbnail. pushing the content/thumbnails under it down.

the only thing i can think of is to (excuse my phrasing and terminology):

construct a loop featuring a counter. render the thumb and its tags, then when its time to render the corresponding information that would expand, put all of that in an array (if possible, i suck with arrays). then, once the counter has reached 3, close up the container div tag (fluid-grid from the explanation up above) and render each array entries. then back to out putting the next row.

am i going in the correct direction?

in any event, if any one knows how i would go about constructing this page, id really appreciate it, thanks all.

Comment: Welcome, OJ. Do you have any code to show? Like a basic loop running that puts out the html as you've described? What specific part of this do you need help with?

Comment: Why not make a start and update your answer with your code?

Comment: sorry guys. Im not getting any notifications that i have replies. Im currently trying to work on getting this whole thing comped out, ill report back with what my client decides to do.

Answer (score 0):

A little ambigious and i'm sure theres many ways to achieve this but if it were me:

I'd first loop all the images out with their post ID's attached.

Then Have a .click() AJAX load to grab the post information through into the format you want ([like this](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2010/04/01/loading-wordpress-posts-with-ajax-and-jquery/)) just so all information isn't pulled on initial load

Hope that helps a bit

Comment: cool thanks! ill try this! i appreciate it. Ill let you know if it works.